# how does strchr in C++ guarantee its caller that it will not modify the string passed as parameter

Tags: c++, c, constants, const-correctness

In C the definition of strchr is as follows

```
char * strchr(const char *s, int c);
```

This declaration guarantees the user that strchr will not modify the contents of 's' (unless the code uses explicit typecasting).

The issue as gleaned from web is that this definition casts way the "const" attribute when it returns a pointer and hence in 'C++' this is not "const correct".

The solution in C++ seems to be to have overloaded functions

```
const char * strchr ( const char * str, int character );
      char * strchr (       char * str, int character );
```

While this is "const safe", I am unable to understand how the second declaration
    char * strchr (char * str, int character) 
promise its caller that it will not modify its parameter.

Comment: I guess by definition, and not by convention

Comment: The second version is for non-const strings. C++ is somewhat different about how to handle `const`. These are actaully true constants, in C it is merely a promise by the programmer; it is still a variable (but might reside in read-only memory, so writes are _undefined behaviour_).

Comment: Recall originally `const` did not exist in C and so the C function was `char * strchr(char *s, int c);` and that function did not modify `s` either, but that was only "enforced" per documentation and not in code.  (or before that is was `char *strchr(s,c)`.)

Comment: True. But once 'const' was introduced, was not strchr modified to "char * strchr(const char *s, int c) with the intent that the "const" in parameter would be clear of documenting to the  caller that this function will not modify it's parameters.  Also, the 'c' compiler would then use this and then if the developer of the "strchr" happened to modify this (without explicit type conversion) flag that as warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make such a promise. Quite the contrary, it provides its caller with a way to modify the string through the returned pointer. That's why this version can only be invoked with a non-const pointer.

Comment: but the first parameter is "const char *". So it would accept both const and non-const pointers. What you mention is one of the common uses caes of this function.  But the way it is declared clearly shows the intent that strchr will not modify it's paramter.

Comment: @ksrikanth Your question was "*I am unable to understand how the second declaration char \* strchr (char \* str, int character) promise its caller that it will not modify its parameter.*" The first parameter is *not* `const char *`.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ version is const-correct and C version is not because with C you can accidentally write this

```
const char str[] = "Hello world";
*strchr(str, 'o') = 'O'; // undefined behaviour
```

or this

```
*strchr("Hello world", 'o') = 'O'; // undefined behaviour
```

While the C++ version would fail at compile time

```
const char str[] = "Hello world";
*strchr(str, 'o') = 'O'; // error: assignment of read-only location
```

As you can see, given a signature you can't prove an arbitrary function won't modify the data pointed to (even worse, consider that a function could `const_cast` away the pointer and modify it anyway!). But that wasn't the point of this overloading, the point was to make *accidental* errors harder to make.

Comment: I understand why C++ version is correct. But I am not sure if it has covered all the cases for which "const" keyword was added to parameter  "strchr" in the 'C' language.   One of the reasons that i understand that "const" was added to strchr was to declare to the caller that strchr will never modify the variable that is passed to it.   So, does it mean that in C++ such guarantee can never be made.